# Splitting String in specific pattern and remove the last digit in groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a value of one variable in this format `version = 6.1.0.75`. I am trying to write a logic in groovy/gradle to change the value of this string from `6.1.0.75` to `6_1_0`

I want to remove the last digit (`75`) and keep first 3 digit `6.1.0` in 6_1_0 format. The value of the version variable could be anything.

Can someone tell how we can achieve this?

I need to do the same thing in groovy:

```
a = 1.2.3.67890
echo $a | cut -d "." -f1,2,3 | tr "." "_"
```

gives:

```
1_2_3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try:

```
'6.1.0.75'.split('\\.')[0..-2].join('_')
```